# How to parse JSON items, and then display the results using the TListView component?

Tags: json, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria, tlistview

Here is the Json data :

```json
{
  "meta": {
      "code": 200,
      "disclaimer": "Usage subject to terms"
  },
  "response": {
      "date": "2022-09-16T01:59:00Z",
      "base": "USD",
      "rates": {
          "ADA": 2.13250314,
          "ZMW": 15.57878043,
          "ZWD": 361.9,
          "ZWL": 604.11755006
      }
  }
}
```

I want to parse the `rates` object using the [`TJSONIterator.Next`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.Builders.TJSONIterator.Next), [`TJSONIterator.Recurse`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.Builders.TJSONIterator.Recurse), and [`TJSONIterator.Return`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.Builders.TJSONIterator.Return) methods, and display the retrieved data using the `TListView`.

But the code I wrote shows me only one item inside `rates`, and on the other hand when I do it with the Memo all items are displayed.

```pascal
ListView1.Items.Clear;
ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
try
  oItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  try
    while True do
    begin
      while LIterator.Next do
        if LIterator.&Type in [TJsonToken.StartObject, TJsonToken.StartArray] then
        begin                                                // Iterate into Rates object and display all the Ccies + Values
          LIterator.Recurse;
          LIterator.Next('rates');
          LIterator.Recurse;
          while LIterator.Next do
          begin
            LIterator.Recurse;
            oItem.Text := LIterator.Key {+': '+ LIterator.AsValue.ToString};
          end;
        end;
      if LIterator.InRecurse then
        LIterator.Return
      else
        Break;
    end;
  finally
    LIterator.Free;
  end;
finally
  ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: You only add one item, and so that's what you get

Comment: Move the call to `ListView1.Items.Add()` to inside your inner `while LIterator.Next` loop

Comment: Yes, it works! Adding `ListView1.Items.Add()` inside the last `while LIterator.Next` loop displays all the items.key... Thanks